# How to define mongoose schema for setting the same model as type for its embedded document

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

Say I am creating a model called 'Comment' but the reply field of the comment model should be of type 'Comment'. Is it possible? If so help me

```
const commentSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  comment: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  author: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    required: true
  },
  reply: {
    type: [Comments]
  }
},
  {
    timestamps: true
  })

const Comments = mongoose.model('Comment', commentSchema)
module.exports = Comments
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `this` to self reference.

```
 const commentSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  comment: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  author: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    required: true
  },
  reply: {
    type: [this]
  }
},
  {
    timestamps: true
  })

const Comments = mongoose.model('Comment', commentSchema)
module.exports = Comments
```